# Determinant of a special block matrix in terms of a singular matrix

Tags: determinant, block-matrices

I have a matrix $A$ with $\det A = 0$. How can one prove that for $Z = \begin{pmatrix} \Re[A]  & -\Im[A] \\ \Im[A]  & \Re[A]  \end{pmatrix}$, is such that $\det Z =0$?

Comment: I think that (first row) + i * (second row) = (A iA)

Answer (score 1):

Since $\det A = 0$ i, we know that there is some non zero $x$ such that $Ax = 0$.

Then, $y = \begin{pmatrix} \Re[x] \\ \Im [x]\end{pmatrix} $ is non zero and :
\begin{align}
Zy &= \begin{pmatrix}
\Re [A] & -\Im[A]\\ \Im[A] & \Re[A]
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \Re[x] \\ \Im [x]\end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix}
\Re[A]\Re[x] - \Im[A]\Im[x] \\
\Re[A]\Im[x] + \Im[A]\Re[x] 
\end{pmatrix}\\
&= \begin{pmatrix}
\Re[Ax]\\ \Im[Ax]
\end{pmatrix} \\
&= 0
\end{align}

The next-to-last step follows from :
\begin{align}
Ax &= (\Re[A] + i\Im[A])(\Re[x] + i\Im[x]) \\&= (\Re[A]\Re[x] - \Im[A]\Im [x] ) + i (\Re[A]\Im[x] + \Im[A]\Re[x])
\end{align}
Therefore, $\det Z = 0$

Comment: can you explain the step before the last step?